# AWS Lambda stripe payment backend, PCI concerns?

Tags: stripe-payments, aws-lambda, pci-compliance, amazon-cognito

I hope to build a mobile app that sends credit card information to an aws-lambda microservice, which then submits that information to stripe. I'm concerned about PCI compliance/security, and I'm wondering if there is something I'm missing. The following is my plan:

1) Users sign in using PCI compliant passwords - and are assigned unique ids and get cognito access keys.

2) Users enter payment information in the mobile app. The app then sends that credit card data via POST request using HTTPS to a cognito authenticated aws-lambda instance (api gateway is used to create endpoints).

3) Upon a successful post request the app deletes the local credit card data.

4) The lambda instance decrypts encrypted stripe secret access keys using KMS.

5) The lambda instance uses Stripe NodeJS sdk to send the data to stripe and stores stripe tokens in databases.

6) At no point does the Lambda instance save ANY credit card data - it ONLY writes Stripe tokens to the database.

Is there anything I'm missing here? Is there something I should be concerned about?

EDIT:

Additional Info:
Credit card details are collected within the app and stored in the app state until they are deleted. The https POST does not use Stripe tools because I'm using React Native.

Comment: One thing to think about for #2 --- how are you collecting / POSTing card data? Are you using one of the tools that Stripe provides --- Elements or Checkout, one of the mobile SDKs? If you're doing that it should ease PCI compliance concerns as card details never pass through your server at all. Posting raw PANs, even if you are not retaining them will make compliance trickier.

Comment: @duck This is my main concern - the POST request to lambda is simply https; it is not using Stripe's tools. The reason for this is that I'm developing in react native, and stripe doesn't have any SDK for that. Should I do some other thing here? E.g. Encrypt the data -> https post -> decrypt inside lambda?

Comment: I'm not a PCI expert, but other points of concern that come to mind are: server logs (recording POST requests, does AWS record these in their own logs for tracking usage?) and how to restrict physical access to the server.

Comment: Have you looked at using Stripe's JavaScript API? Or this? http://blog.bigbinary.com/2015/11/03/using-stripe-api-in-react-native-with-fetch.html https://github.com/lrettig/react-native-stripe

Comment: Finally another point to consider is that if you're not selling physical goods, you'll most likely need to implement payments through the App Store or Google Play so that Apple and Google can take their cut.

Comment: @Rob I have looked at the blog you linked - basically they are just using requests to access Stripe's api. I'm reluctant to do that directly from within the app for two reasons: (1) it is architecturally inelegant (2) I have to embed the stripe secret key in the app. Furthermore, I cant use Stripe's Javascript SDK because it depends on NodeJS, and React Native doesn't run on that.

Comment: @Logister - you could write a wrapping service to handle the requests / responses to Stripe thus making it more elegant. And you'd only need to include the public API key, not the private API key.

Comment: @Rob - of course! The public key! Now I feel stupid. Thank you! If you like, feel free to write a response with this information and I'll give you answer points.

Comment: @Logister - no worries. Answer added. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to our discussion in the comments, you could write a service wrapper to POST the data directly to Stripe using their JavaScript API. You'd just need to embed the public API key in your app.

See the solution in this blog post: http://blog.bigbinary.com/2015/11/03/using-stripe-api-in-react-native-with-fetch.html